# How to use DISTINCT with a text data type?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to use the DISTINCT statement for the query below but I also need to add another column from a third table which has a text data type.

This query returns the results I'm looking for.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    a."APT_ID", a."BLDG", a."UNIT", a."UTILITIES", 
    b."ADDRESS", b."CITY"
FROM 
    APT_INFO a
INNER JOIN 
    BLDG_INFO b ON a."APT_ID" = b."APT_ID"
```

How can I add this column to the report above? I get results when I run this query standalone but when I add to the query above I receive an error message.

```
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT CAST ("SUMMARY" AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS 'Lay Summary' FROM TEST 

SELECT DISTINCT 
    a."APT_ID", a."BLDG", a."UNIT", a."UTILITIES", b."ADDRESS", b."CITY"
FROM
    APT_INFO a
INNER JOIN 
    BLDG_INFO b ON a."APT_ID" = b."APT_ID"
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         CAST ("SUMMARY" AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS 'Lay Summary' 
     FROM TEST
```

Error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 48
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Hello @JeanDavis, you haven't completed the `INNER JOIN` for your test table, complete the sub-query, and `ON` clause with reference columns same what you have done between `API_ID` and `BLDG_INFO` tables

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your quick response. I understand text data types will be removed in the future. I'm not the DBA to make that decision. I'm only trying to extract data. I created this test database and tables since we don't have a DEV environment.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT 
    a."APT_ID", a."BLDG", a."UNIT", a."UTILITIES", b."ADDRESS", b."CITY"
FROM
    APT_INFO a
INNER JOIN 
    BLDG_INFO b ON a."APT_ID" = b."APT_ID"
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         CAST (c."SUMMARY" AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS 'Lay Summary' 
     FROM TEST c ON a."APT_ID"=c."ID" 
ORDER BY "BLDG" ASC; I'm still getting an error. Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 71
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'.